# Errors were encountered while processing: snapd

Tags: apt, updates, dpkg, dependencies, snap

ubuntu@RHC-395:~$ sudo apt-get install snap

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 snapd : Depends: cgroup-lite but it is not going to be installed
         Recommends: linux-generic-lts-xenial but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

ubuntu@RHC-395:~$ sudo apt-get -f install

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  snapd
The following packages will be upgraded:
  snapd
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/13.2 MB of archives.
After this operation, 594 kB disk space will be freed.
`Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y`
(Reading database ... 334787 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../snapd_2.42.1_amd64.deb ...
Failed to stop snapd.service: Unit snapd.service not loaded.
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 5
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
Failed to stop snapd.core-fixup.service: Unit snapd.core-fixup.service not loaded.
Failed to stop snapd.failure.service: Unit snapd.failure.service not loaded.
Failed to stop snapd.seeded.service: Unit snapd.seeded.service not loaded.
Failed to stop snapd.service: Unit snapd.service not loaded.
Failed to stop snapd.snap-repair.service: Unit snapd.snap-repair.service not loaded.
Failed to stop snapd.snap-repair.timer: Unit snapd.snap-repair.timer not loaded.
Failed to stop snapd.system-shutdown.service: Unit snapd.system-shutdown.service not loaded.
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/snapd_2.42.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 5
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/snapd_2.42.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

This looks a bit messed up but any help will be appreciated.
I have tried configuring and almost everything but the same cycle keeps on repeating.
configure code doesnt work and everything else gives a output regarding snapd.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting and https://askubuntu.com/editing-help for guidance on formatting your questions, answers, and comments here.

Comment: What version Ubuntu?

Comment: Looks like you're experiencing this bug on Ubuntu 16.04. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd/+bug/1732494

Answer (score 1):

I suspect `sudo service --status-all` may list a snapd instance. In that case, stop it with `sudo systemcl stop snapd`. It's either this, OR you have a lock set on dpkg. You may check the latter with `pgrep -f 'dpkg|apt` (successor of `ps afx|grep dpkg`), and remove the *stuck* lock with `sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock`.